# Why Facebook Prepend Comments to their JSONP responses?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, jsonp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook graph api JSONP format , what does the /* */ in first line signify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034515/facebook-graph-api-jsonp-format-what-does-the-in-first-line-signify)

https://graph.facebook.com/woho?callback=sdf:

```
/**/ sdf({
   "error": {
      "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: woho",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 803
   }
});
```

So what's the point of the `/**/` in the beginning?